# Canvas.drawText cannot get value from R.string

Tags: android, layout

i use canvas in overlay class.
Code
`canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.destination), (float) point2.x+4, (float) point2.y+4, paint);`
error is no resource found.
i tried

```
final Resources r = Resources.getSystem();
```

r.getString(android.R.string.untitled);

and

```
getResources().getString(R.String.nameHere);
```

but cannot solve it.
anyone can help me

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes eclipse won't update the R-class properly. Then try to clean/close+open your project.

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports to make sure you've imported your R class, not android.R class. Getting strings is usually done by `activity.getResources().getString(int id)`. Hope this helps.